# In android progressar resets it value when app is in background

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a counter with a circular progress bar. When the counter starts, the progress bar is also starting from counter value, but when it's running in the background and again open app... the circular progress bar starts from 0, but the counter runs correctly as per value. In this case I need the progress bar not to start from 0.

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int counter;
    Button button;
    public boolean isrunningtime = false;
    TextView textView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    long millisUntilFinished = 0;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        Log.i("Tag", "Started service");
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));

        Log.i("Tag", "Registered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        Log.i("Tag", "Stopped service");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            Log.i("Tag", "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                progressBar.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));

            Log.i("progress", "" + (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            textView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: show BroadcastService.class file

Comment: Remove unregisterReceiver from onPause() and onStop() method and assign registerReceiver() in onCreate() instead of onResume()

Answer (score 0):

put the `unregisterReceiver(br)` only in `onDestroy()` instead of `onStop()` and `onPause()`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `unregisterReceiver(br);` from onStop() and onPause(), And Move `registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));` from onResume() to onCreate()